# Apache POI: cell.setCellFormula not giving the desired value when excel is generated

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I am able to generate the excel file but the cell which contains the formula(suppose to show the total sum of the integer values of the column) is showing value 0 initially. Then, when i edit some of the column cells it gets updated with the sum of the values of **ONLY** the edited cells and not adding up those of the unedited cells.

My piece of code is:

```
Cell cell = row.createCell(size - 2);
cell.setCellValue("Total");
cell = row.createCell(size - 1);
cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
cell.setCellFormula("SUM(D3:D4)");
```

Also, i tried by adding further these codes below the above code.

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator =  wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
```

But it still gave the same result. Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you over writing just after `cell.setCellFormula("SUM(D3:D4)");`?

Comment: i tried without the overwriting too. but shows no effect

Comment: is there other way of setting cell formula? if so, please do let me know. I can't seem to get any luck with this.

Comment: Did you try reading the [Apache POI Formula Evaluation Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why it doesn't work for you, try this code, it works for me.

```
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
    Row row = sheet.createRow(3);// Row 4
    Cell cell = row.createCell(3); // Cell 'D'
    cell.setCellValue(10);

    row=sheet.createRow(2);// Row 3
    cell=row.createCell(3);// Cell 'D' 
    cell.setCellValue(2);

    cell=row.createCell(4);// Cell 'E'
    cell.setCellValue("Total");
    cell = row.createCell(5);// Cell 'F'
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
    cell.setCellFormula("SUM(D3:D4)");
```

The only difference is that I use `Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA` instead of `HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA`, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: I appreciate you giving your time. But earlier i have tried with that too but it was of no help. However, i have this way this time

cell.setCellFormula(D3+D4). and it works well. However, i am not sure if this is a safe way of writing the code.

Comment: If my code is not working with you and it is working perfectly for me, maybe the error is in other parts of your code or your excel configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Use wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true); before closing file

it will calculate the formula

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your changing the style of the cell later on in the code